# What is a catalytic domain?

Tags: human-biology, bacteriology, homework, medicine

I have to answer a few questions from an article I'm reading, and I am just really confused on defining "catalytic domain." I have to relate it to the antibiotic Teixobactin. Is catalytic domain the same as the enzyme's active site?

Answer (score 4):

The catalytic domain is roughly referring to the same part of the protein as an active site and may be used interchangeably in some circumstances:

See [here](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Catalytic+domain), where "catalytic domain" redirects to "active site."

**There is, however, a difference**:

From a free online [medical dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Catalytic+domain):

> **active site**: 
>   the place on the surface of an enzyme where its catalytic action occurs.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_domain):

> **catalytic domain**: structurally conserved (tertiary) structure containing the catalytic function of the protein.

To further clarify: the ***catalytic domain*** is the 3D structural independent folding unit of the protein that *contains* an active site, while the ***active site*** (aka "catalytic site) is the area located *within* the catalytic domain where substrate molecules bind and undergo a chemical reaction.

Comment: More precisely, the 'catalytic domain' is the domain of the protein that *contains* the active site. Of course, there are different definitions of the word 'domain', but a simple one might be an independent folding unit of the protein.

Comment: @gilleain very true. I will update my answer.